# Flutter sticky header list add items on scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello fellow developers,

For my first Flutter project I need to use a list with sticky headers and infinite scroll. I found a very nice library for this purpose. 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header

Final goal is to fetch new items into the list from my database by scrolling further down.
For testing purposes I added a button to add a random item to my list. However the UI is not updated when the function is called. I am very new to Flutter. Below my code. How can I update the UI every time an item is added to the list without recreating the widget.

```
class AppScaffold2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppScaffold2State createState() => _AppScaffold2State();
}

class _AppScaffold2State extends State<AppScaffold2> {

  final CustomScrollView x =  CustomScrollView(
      slivers: new List<Widget>(),
      reverse: false,
    );

    int counter = 0;

  add(Widget w){
    x.slivers.add(w);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultStickyHeaderController(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: x),
          MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () => fetch(),
            child: Text('add to list')  
          ) 
        ],),)
      ),
    );
  }

  fetch() {
    x.slivers.add(_StickyHeaderList(index: counter));
    counter++;
  }
}

class _StickyHeaderList extends StatelessWidget {
  const _StickyHeaderList({
    Key key,
    this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverStickyHeader(
      header: Header(index: index),
      sliver: SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (context, i) => ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              child: Text('$index'),
            ),
            title: Image.network(
            "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ixkoVwKQaJg/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEZCNACELwBSFXyq4qpAwsIARUAAIhCGAFwAQ==&rs=AOn4CLDrYjizQef0rnqvBc0mZyU3k13yrg",
          ),
          ),
          childCount: 6,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using setState() in fetch Method.
like this.

````
fetch() {
    x.slivers.add(_StickyHeaderList(index: counter));
     setState(() {
        _counter++;
     });  
}```
````

Comment: It works if I make a seperate list for the slivers and use this list inside the customScrollView. After updating the list in setState it is now rendered to the UI. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Update state using setState.

```
 fetch() {
    x.slivers.add(_StickyHeaderList(index: counter));
     setState(() {
        _counter++;
     }); 
    }
```